# Images overlap on browser resize. How to space them out?

Tags: html, css, browser, size, overlap

I have a photo gallery and my photos are diplayed as thumbnails.
When I resize the browser they move as I want them to but instead of getting evenly pushed down on to the next line they instead go down but overlap oeach other.

When the browser is full, the images display fine. Here is a screenshot showing the images moved and overlapping when the browser is smaller:

[image]

I currently use this code if it helps.

```
div.photoimg
  {
  margin:2px;
  padding: 5px;
  height:auto;
  width:auto;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  }
div.img photoimg
  {
  display:inline;
  margin:3px;
  }
div.img a:hover img
  {
  border:1px solid #0000ff;
  }
div.desc
  {
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:normal;
  width:200px;
  margin:2px;
  }
```

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but try instead of 
`div.img photoimg { display:inline; }`
use 
`div.img photoimg { display:block; }`